# Java Paint component into bitmap

Tags: java, components, bitmap, paint

I need to draw the content of a component and all its subcomponents in a bitmap. 
The following code works perfectly if i want to draw the entire component :

```
public void printComponent(Component c, String format, String filename) throws IOException {
// Create a renderable image with the same width and height as the component
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // Render the component and all its sub components
    c.paintAll(image.getGraphics());

    // Render the component and ignoring its sub components
    c.paint(image.getGraphics());
// Save the image out to file
ImageIO.write(image, format, new File(filename));
```

}

but i didn't find a way for drawing only a **region** of this component. 
Any idea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to translate like this:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
g.translate(-100, -100);

c.paintComponent(g);

g.dispose();
```

---

Full example with output:

[image: Resulting image]

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.add(new JTable(new DefaultTableModel() {
        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 10;
        }
        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return 10;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
            return row + " " + column;
        }
    }));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.translate(-100, -100);

    frame.paintComponents(g);

    g.dispose();

    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("frame.png"));
}
```

Comment: It wont't draw the component's region beginining at the point 0,0 in the bitmap !

Comment: The clip I set was an example, you need to set this region to something useful for you.

Comment: If I want to draw the region starting at point (100,100) and with a siez of 100*100, I need to create a bitmap with a size of 100*100 and so what are the parameters for the setClip method ?

Comment: Fixed solution again (remove the clip).

Answer (score 1):

The [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class simplifies this process for you.