# How do I paint a specific region of a component into a separate graphics context?

Tags: java, swing, printing, paint

What I'm trying to do is print the entire content of a component which requires painting the component into the graphics context that is given by a printing subroutine. What I want it to do is paint only the page size of a component (starting with a clip rectangle size of (0,0),(pageWidth,pageHeight). I already have the math done right, it is just a matter of figuring out how to paint only a specific rectangle region of a component for each page's graphic context. setClip() seems to limit what region can be painted in the graphics context and doesn't seem helpful for what I want to do.

Simply put, I want to paint a rectangle region (50,50),(100,100) of a component into the (0,0),(50,50) region of a graphics context.

Would this be possible without using a large amount of memory (such as using a huge BufferedImage to paint the entire component and using smaller sub-images for painting individual pages)?

Comment: There is a good answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245179/java-paint-component-into-bitmap).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Paint component into bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245179/java-paint-component-into-bitmap)